# Compile Twitter bootstrap 3 docs (How to)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, makefile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to compile bootstrap 3. I have the repo cloned on my local. I run make in the bootstrap directory.

```
aaas-imac:bootstrap aaa$ make



Building Bootstrap...
--------------------------------------------------
Running JSHint on JavaScript...             ✔ Done
Compiling LESS with Recess...               ✔ Done
Prepping documentation assets...            ✔ Done
Compiling and minifying JavaScript...       ✔ Done
--------------------------------------------------
Success!

Thanks for using Bootstrap,
<3 @mdo and @fat

aaas-imac:bootstrap aaa$
```

I don't see the compiled docs anywhere?

Comment: Another option download a fork of the docs: https://github.com/AAlakkad/Bootstrap-3-Offline-Docs

Comment: Works for me. Download the zip file, extract all, and point your browser to index.html therein. Easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.0's docs are built using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). To view the docs locally, you'll need to [install Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) to run a local server.

Comment: The link doesn't point to the docs. On the page is only a link to the github issue of Bootstrap 3

Comment: At the time when my answer was posted it did point to a hosted copy of the Bootstrap 3 docs. They've since removed it. You'll have to start up a local Jekyll server to few the documentation now.

Comment: @ZainShaikh I wrote a post about it: http://blog.greenmice.info/2013/04/twitter-bootstap-3-building-reading-docs.html

tl;dr;
jekyll . /tmp/bootstrap3-docs/ ; cd /tmp/bootstrap3-docs ; python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

Comment: For those interested. I compiled the docs and put it up at  http://bootstrap.harp.io. I'll try to keep them up until the bootstrap team get them online.

Comment: @sintaxi the docs seems to be not up to date. It's possible to share how did you build it or update to the latest version? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

To install Jekyll and build: (Note for windows see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853614/1596547)

1. install rubygems (sudo `apt-get install rubygems`)
2. (sudo) `gem install jekyll`
3. <strike>go to the `./docs` dir of your bootstrap install (see also: [Explore and install Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/explore-and-install-twitter-bootstrap-3/))</strike>
4. run `jekyll --server` from your bootstrap dir
5. visit `http://localhost:9001/` <strike>`http://localhost:9001/docs.html`</strike> in your browser

NB the default port for WEBrick will be 9001. If this port is not avaible an other port will be used: `WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
 INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=30728 port=4000`

When you visit `http://localhost:9001/` you will find a home screen. <strike>The "View docs" button links to /docs/ while the docs are on docs.html</strike> See below:

[image: Twitter's Bootstrap 3.0.0 Docs]

<strike>Now (jul 10 2013) the navbar links seems broken (missing .html) so use `http://localhost:9001/javascript.html` in stead of `http://localhost:9001/javascript`. See also: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/8443</strike>

**Using git** (jekyll already installed):

```
git clone --branch 3.0.0-wip git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
cd bootstrap
jekyll --server
```

visit `http://localhost:9001/` or `http://localhost:4000/`

**UPDATE** [@lee-whitney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700206/lee-whitney) suggests to use `jekyll serve` instead of `jekyll --server`. The `jekyll serve` command creates a directory with the html files of the docs. You could serve this files on a (local) webserver. `jekyll serve` don't start a (jekyll) server. I test this commands on linux (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) with Jekyll 0.12.1

Answer (score 5):

In Windows ( perfectly tested by me not sure of linux ) :

> Step1 : Download Bootstrap3 : github.com/twitter/bootstrap/archive/3.0.0-wip.zip 
>   Step2 : Download Ruby : [Click Here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76955/rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p195.exe) 
>   Step3 : Download Devkit : [Click Here](https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) and extract it to some directory.
>   Step4 : Go to devkit direcory via ruby terminal and execute following commands

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
gem install jekyll --version '= 0.11.0'
```

Version step is very crucial as I was not able to compile the docs in latest version of jekyll so I switched to older version.

> Step5 : go to the root dir of your bootstrap directory
>   Step6 : run jekyll --server 
>   Step7 : visit localhost:9001/ or localhost:4000/ in your browser ( one of them will surely work )

Comment: Thanks. Step5 is obsolete, the jekyll server command must be run from teh root.

Comment: This was really useful for the Windows environment

Answer (score 3):

I tried Abhishek's method and it did work. But not completely. I still got some Fluid errors.

So I did a lot of digging around and found a solution. Compiling Bootstrap 3 is bit more annoying than 2.3.2

Do the following to compile and get it running.

1. Get Bootstrap 3 master zip
2. Get Ruby 1.9.3
3. Get DevKit
4. Install Python 2.7 and update the PATH Environment Variable with the python directory
5. Get Jekyll 1.x as mentioned on the GitHUb page of Bootstrap.  
   Go to devkit directory via ruby terminal and execute following commands

   > ruby dk.rb init
   >   ruby dk.rb install
   >   gem install jekyll
6. Uninstall pygments 0.5.2 and install pygments 0.5.0

   > gem uninstall pygments.rb --version "=0.5.2"
   >   gem install pygments.rb --version "=0.5.0"
7. Go to the root directory of the extracted bootstrap source in your terminal and run the following

   > chcp 65001
   >   jekyll serve

Now browse to localhost:9001 and there, you should see the docs hosted locally.

> **NOTE**: *Once compiled, you can access those pages without having to run the jekyll serve command every time. Just open the html pages as you would do with any locally saved web page.*
>
> *Also, feel free to delete the extracted DevKit files as you won't be using them again for viewing the docs.*

Comment: You sir, are fantastic.  I was wracking my brain over this for a while. +1

Comment: This got me a long way, but the final step to compile the doc files permanently didn't work for me. I find that I have to go to the bootstrap directory and run jekyll --server every time to view the docs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the compressed docs, no need to do anything but read. Full downloadable Bootstrap 3 docs.

http://web3canvas.com/item/bootstrap-3-docs/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution

To install Jekyll, Rouge and build:

if you dont have ruby installed - http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/2-jekyll-gem/

1. from comand promt, cd into your bootstrap folder
2. run `npm install` - if you run into problems, do a `npm update`
3. if jekyll was not install, run `gem install jekyll`
4. then run `gem install rouge`
5. run `jekyll server` from your bootstrap folder
6. visit http://localhost:9001/

Comment: tested July 6, 2015, as of now you seem to need rouge so this is correct answer

Answer (score 0):

`Update: For Bootstrap version 3.3.4`

To run the `Twitter Bootstrap(v3.3.4)` docs locally, I performed following steps and hope it might help others.

**Steps:**

- `gem install jekyll` (need to have `Ruby`, `Rubygems` installed)
- `git clone --branch gh-pages git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git`

  (now `gh-pages` branch holds all docs stuff)
- `cd bootstrap`
- `jekyll serve`
- Visit `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` default server url