# unable to run bootstrap 3 with jekyll server locally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just downloaded [twitter bootstrap branch 3.0.0-wip](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/3.0.0-wip), and recieving error when compiling.

I also downloaded [jekyll-boilerplate](https://github.com/necolas/jekyll-boilerplate) and it ran successfully using `jekyll server`.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Command executed:**

```
D:\Zain\github\bootstrap\source>jekyll --server
```

**Error recieved:**

```
Configuration from D:/Zain/github/bootstrap/source/_config.yml
Building site: ./docs -> ./_gh_pages
Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in docs.html
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:72:in 'initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:72:in 'new'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:72:in 'encode'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:22:in 'dump'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:225:in 'block in mentos'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:65:in 'timeout'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:209:in 'mentos'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.7/lib/pygments/popen.rb:192:in 'highlight'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:54:in 'render_pygments'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:44:in 'render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:106:in 'block in render_all'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:93:in 'each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:93:in 'render_all'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in 'render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:124:in 'render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:132:in 'render!'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:79:in 'do_layout'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/page.rb:100:in 'render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:204:in 'block in render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:203:in 'each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:203:in 'render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in 'process'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:264:in '<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in 'load'
C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in '<main>'
Build Failed
```

Comment: Did you `make docs` ?

Comment: Follow this answer..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16853614/2439715

Hope it helps..!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seams, that it does not work with jekyll 2.0. Try an older version like 1.9.3. See:

http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/yEuPjlPlMao

**Update:**

I found a page that describe the installation of jekyll for windows, look here:

http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2011/09/01/runningjekyllwindows.html

**Update 2:**

There is now a GitHub project:

https://github.com/juthilo/run-jekyll-on-windows

> This repository is intended to provide Windows users with instructions to successfully run Jekyll - not just at the time of its creation but hopefully also in the future, when common solutions become outdated once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the documentation about Bootstrap 3 and you don't want to install Jekyll then use httrack to windows and save the page you want. Search for the program on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

`Update: For Bootstrap version 3.3.4`

To run the `Twitter Bootstrap(v3.3.4)` docs locally, I performed following steps and hope it might help others.

**Steps:**

- `gem install jekyll` (need to have `Ruby`, `Rubygems` installed)
- `git clone --branch gh-pages git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git`

  (now `gh-pages` branch holds all docs stuff)
- `cd bootstrap`
- `jekyll serve`
- Visit `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` default server url