# Bootstrap modal showing or not depending on bootstrap version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to web programming so I used a couple of templates to create my website, all of them related to Twitter Bootstrap.

My login page correctly shows Bootstrap modals. These are the imports I used there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The problems start with the main page after login. It was taken from another template and it uses the following imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard2.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

As you can see the only change is the source of Bootstrap. In the first case I downloaded it to the css folder, while in the second case it's taken directly from the server.

As a result the modals do not show in the main page (the second one). The screen fades to black but no modal is shown.

[image]

If I modify the imports of the main page to take Bootstrap from the css folder instead of the server, the modals do show, but the layout of the whole page is ruined:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard2.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I just checked (no idea why it never occurred to me before) that my local Bootstrap is v2.3.2, while the one on the server is v3.1.1. Can it make such a difference, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some research I solved my problem, I hope others will benefit from it.

This post actually solved it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575687/bootstrap-3-0-modal)

Apparently the syntax for the modal in Bootstrap 3 is different and among other things it has to include these lines:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
```

So I took the example under the link, tweaked it for my purposes and it worked. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add meta tag for responsive in head tag of the page. If not then try to add following meta tag into your head tags of the page.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Hope this will be resolve your problem.

Note : First try this to add into your version in which you imports bootstrap downloaded files.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. The screen still goes black with no modal. But I already found the solution, thanks.