# Images not responsive by default in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

It looks like with the new version 3.0 I have to set the class names of an image to `col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-4` if the image is part of div with the same class names to make the image responsive with all breakpoints.

In version 2 the images CSS properties inherited by default the parent's div properties.

Is this correct?

Comment: It looks like there is a new class for responsive images `.img-responsive`

Answer (score 142):

**Bootstrap 4**

For Bootstrap 4 use Sass (SCSS):

```
// make images responisve by default
img {
  @extend .img-fluid;    
}
```

**answer updated for version 3**

Bootstrap 3 has a special class for responsive images (set max-width to 100%). This class is defined as:

```
.img-responsive {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

Note img tag gets by default:

```
img {
     vertical-align: middle;
     border: 0;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
     max-width: 100% !important;
     }
```

So use `class="img-responsive"` to make your images responsive.

To make all images responsive by default:

**css:** add the code below under the bootstrap css:

```
   img {
          display: block;
          height: auto;
          max-width: 100%;
   }
```

**less:** add the code below in your mixins.less:

```
img {
  &:extend(.img-responsive);
}
```

Note: requires Less 1.4.0. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573240/1596547

### Carousel

img tags inside a [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) are responsive by default

### Semantic rules

<strike>See also the answer of [@its-me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071413/its-me) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18653778/1596547). Using the above to make all your images responsive by default turns your images to [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements). Block level elements are not allowed in paragraphs (`<p>`), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291515/1596547</strike>

As far as i understand the distinction of block-level vs. inline elements is replaced with a more complex set of content categories. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente#Inline_vs._block-level. 
So in HTML5 a p tag can contain any phrasing element intermixed with normal character data. (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) The `img` tag is such a phrasing element. The `img` tag's default value for the display property is indeed `inline-block`. Changing the  display property to block does not violate any of the preceding rules.

Block level elements (`display:block`) take all the available space of their parent, which seems exactly what you expect for responsive images. So setting `display: block;` seems a reasonable choice, which has to be preferred above the `inline-block` declaration.

Images inside p elements which require `inline-block` as suggest by [@its-me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071413/its-me) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18653778/1596547) should maybe not be responsive at all.

Comment: Sass: `img { @extend .img-responsive; }`

Answer (score 13):

Excellent suggestion by @BassJobsen, but I'd use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;` as that feels more semantic <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291515/1071413)</sup> (which means you can be a bit more sure you are not messing up somewhere else).

So, mine would look like this:

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

*Please do let me know if my understanding is flawed. :)*

---

**[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291515/1071413)**: For one, images are almost always wrapped in a block-level element if that's the use case; and then again, we also use images in elements like paragraphs (`p`), where an `inline-block` would be more appropriate than a `block` element.

Comment: interesting stuff. If you set a width (max-width in this case) the element will always be / become a block level element as i understood. So following the semantic rules you can't use an image with max-height in a `<p>`. Set the display inline-block maybe feels better but is not. This should be the reason Bootstrap don't make images responsive by default now.

Comment: @BassJobsen Here's more to support my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2402773/1071413

Comment: @its-me It seems that in HTML5 the distinction of block-level vs. inline elements is replaced with a more complex set of content categories. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Block-level_vs._inline

Comment: After initially using the accepted solution, I ran into a few undesirable outcomes. Separately, I also arrived at the same conclusion of using inline-block which solved those issues without any negative side affects that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Got here after trying to figure out if it's safe to apply `img-responsive` for all images.

The answer by @its_me led me to think that it isn't safe to apply this for images under a `p` element.

This does not seems to be what the bootstrap team think.

This is why images are not responsive by default in bootstrap3:

> The summary is that it breaks a ton of unsuspecting third-party widgets (including Google Maps), which understandably don't anticipate the images within them being forcibly resized to other widths. This is why we rolled back Bootstrap v2's "images are responsive by default" approach in Bootstrap v3 in favor of an explicit .img-responsive class.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18178#issuecomment-154180107