# How to make an item responsive in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap theme i designed my self, its quite responsive, adjusts immediately screen size shrinks, but when i added some javascript functionality to an image making it have an overlay on hover, with some little css, the responsiveness of the image got distorted, it never shrinks, and i want the overlay to remain, please i'm pleading if anyone could help in making it retain its responsiveness .... This is html code snippet below, and some inline stylesheet, the rest stylesheets are twitter bootstrap default style sheets

```
<div class="container marketing" style="padding-top: 20px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8"> 
        <span class="label label-info">EXCLUSIVE</span>
        <img id="d1" src="img-data/underage-marriage/nigeria-underage-marriage.jpg">
        <div class="contenthover" style="margin-top:10%;">
            <div class="row-fluid text-center" style="border-bottom:1px #CCC dashed; padding-bottom:3%;">
                <div class="span8" style="border-right:1px #CCC dashed; padding-right: 2%;">
                    <h1 class="pull-right" style="border-bottom:1px #CCC dashed;"><img src="img/brainstorm.png"><b><i>discussion</i></b></h1>
                  <h1><small class="pull-right">Keep your language clean.</small></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="span4" style="padding-top:3%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-danger pull-left" data-loading-text="Loading...">View Article</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="span4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- stylesheet -->
<style>
  .contenthover { padding:20px 20px 10px 20px; }
  .contenthover, .contenthover h3, contenthover a { color:#fff; }
  .contenthover h3,
  .contenthover p {
    margin:0 0 10px 0; line-height:1.4em; padding:0;
  }                    
</style>
```

Comment: Could you show us your stylesheets?

Comment: brother, i've added some inline stylying for the overlay box, the other stylesheets are bootsrap stylesheets ...

Comment: can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the class "row" to "row-fluid".

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this class and make sure it goes after your bootstrap.css files (such as inline) (I remember seeing this Stackoverflow question that may help you out - [Images not responsive by default in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932509/images-not-responsive-by-default-in-twitter-bootstrap-3-0-rc1)...even) if you aren't using Bootstrap 3.0, this will still help.)

```
img {
      display: inline-block;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
```

}

Or you may have to make a separate media query for those images using something like this (for example)...

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Comment: Just one small niggle: please don't recommend inline CSS - it's terrible practice and is difficult to maintain

Comment: I definitely agree. But occasionally people have issues with their CSS files not overriding bootstraps (just a matter of correct placement in the DOM & maybe they are inexperienced...no offense to the OP), so I mentioned it because I guess I was too lazy to explain what I just explained above.

Comment: A fair point, but the best way of doing something often requires the most effort `:)`