# Images not resizing (default Bootstrap classes only)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.0 dist and I am following some Bootstrap tutorial now, trying to learn how it works. I did everything exactly as in the tutorial (it is for v2, so I changed the classes to v3) and I do not use any custom CSS or anything and in the tutorial the images resize when you simply resize the window, but in mine it stays same and wrecks everything. Also according to the tutorial images should stay centered inside the boxes (the 3 images).

Comment: are u used "container" class or "Container-fluid" class

Comment: I used container, because it is updated in v3 from container-fluid to container. Like I mentioned I use updated classes.

Comment: can u give me the links of that tutorial, not able to compare the pblm

Comment: Sorry, it is a video. Like I said I am using default classes. It is very small code, just check the link of my mockup.

Comment: please explain it properly for better answers.

Comment: Doesn't the link above work? Just try to resize the browser window and see that images are not resizing. How simplier can it be?

Comment: Had to add img-responsive to <img> to make images responsive and resize. But does it mean now I have to add that to every image? How was it working without that in v2?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In bootstrap 3 Images are no longer responsive by default. Use *.img-responsive* for fluid  size.

Doc:http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration-dropped

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried adding class="img-responsive" to the problematic images?

Comment: As I understand it v3 doesn't automatically resize - you have to explicitly tag images you want to be responsive.  If you want all images to be responsive, maybe read this past question's answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932509/images-not-responsive-by-default-in-twitter-bootstrap-3