# bootstrap 3 - crop image to fit width & height

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently using a span, that I'm filling with a background to make sure that the images are exactly the same size in all browsers. While I have no complaints about this, I'm missing the opportunity to use the `alt` tag and the potential SEO advantage that it might carry.

Is there a way to do crop an image using html+css only (no js) using the `img` tag?

Comment: why can't you use the `.img-responsive` class? see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932509/images-not-responsive-by-default-in-twitter-bootstrap-3/17933207#17933207

Comment: the problem is that it fits the image as best as it can without stretching it, so images with different aspect ration show up differently. using background setting for a div sets allows the overflow to be cropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SEO for the image is very important perhaps you can include the image with relevant alt, but with style="display: none". Crawlers may be smart enough to rule this out though..!

Comment: that's what I'm thinking, might be penalized more likely than rewarded