# What is the main reason to use new grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to migrate my project from TBS 2.3 to 3 and I've got a question:
Why should I use new classes like col-**-* instead of span*?
Since I can use both of this files, new bootstrap.css and old bootstrap-responsive.css on my   page and old span* do their work well...
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start reading: [Writing Twitter's Bootstrap with upgrading to v3 in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797017/writing-twitters-bootstrap-with-upgrading-to-v3-in-mind/17890898). The new TB3 is written from a mobile first approach and is [not backward-compatible](http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/its-a-shame-the-newest-version-of-githubs-most-popular-projects-is-not-backward-compatible/).

Using the *old* bootstrap-responsive.css will overwrite CSS rules from TB3. Doing this i expect you will got conflicts now or in future. Beside the mobile first approach TB3 also switch to the see `box-sizing: border-box?`: [Why did Bootstrap 3 switch to box-sizing: border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854259/why-did-bootstrap-3-switch-to-box-sizing-border-box/18858771)

To find a solution for your problem read: [Updating Bootstrap to version 3 - what do I have to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do/18069643)

In [this blog](http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/migrate-your-templates-from-twitter-bootstrap-2-x-to-twitter-bootstrap-3/) is suggest the option to use LESS to copy the col-lg-* or col-sm-* properties to span-* i never tried this.
With the latest source it should be possible to construct span* classes with the same properties as  col-*-*. You will have to add these classes to grid.less and use modified mixins from mixins.less.